# is it possible to run jupyter nbconvert in colab to execute on ipynb file that mounts to google drive?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying to execute a series of ipynb notebooks sequentially from another, in colab.

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
    
!jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=600 --execute "/content/drive/My Drive/Mike Education/Code/Extract/Reading Levels/Read in Cleaned Reading Levels Data.ipynb"
```

the request times out, even though if I run the code manually it works fine in well under 10 minutes.

executing debug shows it times out at mount:

```
[NbConvertApp] Searching ['/root/.jupyter', '/root/.local/etc/jupyter', '/usr/etc/jupyter', '/usr/local/etc/jupyter', '/etc/jupyter'] for config files
[NbConvertApp] Looking for jupyter_config in /etc/jupyter
[NbConvertApp] Looking for jupyter_config in /usr/local/etc/jupyter
[NbConvertApp] Looking for jupyter_config in /usr/etc/jupyter
[NbConvertApp] Looking for jupyter_config in /root/.local/etc/jupyter
[NbConvertApp] Looking for jupyter_config in /root/.jupyter
[NbConvertApp] Looking for jupyter_nbconvert_config in /etc/jupyter
[NbConvertApp] Looking for jupyter_nbconvert_config in /usr/local/etc/jupyter
[NbConvertApp] Looking for jupyter_nbconvert_config in /usr/etc/jupyter
[NbConvertApp] Looking for jupyter_nbconvert_config in /root/.local/etc/jupyter
[NbConvertApp] Looking for jupyter_nbconvert_config in /root/.jupyter
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook /content/drive/My Drive/Mike Education/Code/Extract/Reading Levels/Read in Cleaned Reading Levels Data.ipynb to notebook
[NbConvertApp] Notebook name is 'Read in Cleaned Reading Levels Data'
[NbConvertApp] Applying preprocessor: ExecutePreprocessor
[NbConvertApp] Starting kernel: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', '/tmp/tmp1x8jnmqk.json', '--HistoryManager.hist_file=:memory:']
[NbConvertApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:47431
[NbConvertApp] connecting iopub channel to tcp://127.0.0.1:45195
[NbConvertApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:45195
[NbConvertApp] connecting shell channel to tcp://127.0.0.1:44753
[NbConvertApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:44753
[NbConvertApp] connecting stdin channel to tcp://127.0.0.1:55067
[NbConvertApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55067
[NbConvertApp] connecting heartbeat channel to tcp://127.0.0.1:55431
[NbConvertApp] connecting control channel to tcp://127.0.0.1:47431
[NbConvertApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:47431
[NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python3
[NbConvertApp] Executing cell:
#imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from google.colab import drive
from google.colab import files
import gspread
import time
import os
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

drive.mount('/content/drive')

[NbConvertApp] msg_type: status
[NbConvertApp] content: {'execution_state': 'busy'}
[NbConvertApp] msg_type: execute_input
[NbConvertApp] content: {'code': "#imports\nimport pandas as pd\nimport numpy as np\nfrom google.colab import drive\nfrom google.colab import files\nimport gspread\nimport time\nimport os\nfrom google.colab import auth\nauth.authenticate_user()\n\nimport gspread\nfrom google.auth import default\ncreds, _ = default()\n\ngc = gspread.authorize(creds)\nfrom oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials\n\ndrive.mount('/content/drive')\n", 'execution_count': 1}
[NbConvertApp] ERROR | Timeout waiting for execute reply (600s).
[NbConvertApp] Kernel is taking too long to finish, terminating
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 277, in launch_instance
    return super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 340, in start
    self.convert_notebooks()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 510, in convert_notebooks
    self.convert_single_notebook(notebook_filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 481, in convert_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.export_single_notebook(notebook_filename, resources, input_buffer=input_buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 410, in export_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.exporter.from_filename(notebook_filename, resources=resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 179, in from_filename
    return self.from_file(f, resources=resources, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 197, in from_file
    return self.from_notebook_node(nbformat.read(file_stream, as_version=4), resources=resources, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/exporters/notebook.py", line 32, in from_notebook_node
    nb_copy, resources = super(NotebookExporter, self).from_notebook_node(nb, resources, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 139, in from_notebook_node
    nb_copy, resources = self._preprocess(nb_copy, resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 316, in _preprocess
    nbc, resc = preprocessor(nbc, resc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/base.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self.preprocess(nb, resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 405, in preprocess
    nb, resources = super(ExecutePreprocessor, self).preprocess(nb, resources)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/base.py", line 69, in preprocess
    nb.cells[index], resources = self.preprocess_cell(cell, resources, index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 438, in preprocess_cell
    reply, outputs = self.run_cell(cell, cell_index, store_history)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 571, in run_cell
    if self._passed_deadline(deadline):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 541, in _passed_deadline
    self._handle_timeout()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 504, in _handle_timeout
    raise TimeoutError("Cell execution timed out")
TimeoutError: Cell execution timed out
```

Other things I have made sure:
the file can be accessed by anyone who has a link
the file runs fine when I run it manually
I am the only user and this is done on my drive
I believe the kernels are the same? python-3. though I am not 100% sure how to check

Comment: In the output you can see that cells are timing out after 30s even though you configured the timeout to be 600s: `[NbConvertApp] ERROR | Timeout waiting for execute reply (30s).` I don't know why that is happening...

Comment: @WillHoltz yeah I posted a 30 second version but the 10 minute version also doesn't work. I updated it.